# the_permalink not working? wp_list_pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make wp list pages with thumbnails and other good stuff. But when i add the_permalink to my titles thumbnails etc and click on them, they are just refreshing the parent page and not getting the title(page) url. I'll insert what I have maybe someone knows how to fix it? Will be happy for any help ! THANKS

**What I have**

```
 <div id="archive-thumbnails-listing" >
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 352)); ?>

 <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
    <div class="thumb22">
    <div class="thumb20"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'full'); ?></a></div>
     <div class="thumb19"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
     </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

 </div>
```

Comment: use get_the_permalink($page->ID);

Comment: still linking to the parent page (

Comment: same((( in code inspector it is not getting url at all, just ahref tag without nothing:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `echo get_the_permalink($page->ID);`

```
 <div class="thumb19"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to list pages, not posts maybe because of it this code not works for me( THANKS!!

Comment: Exactly, I have copy pasted this code  and now there is no thumbnails and no titles^^